# Multilanguage site URL and language path

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

I am developing a cms in php. 
The language section works like this: 
www.site.com/it/ Default language 
www.site.com/en/ English language

I you go to www.site.com you are automatically redirected to the default language www.site.com/it/
Doing some testing with some tool, I get 302 temporary redirect.. My question is this error: 302 temporary redirect, is this a problem?

Comment: I am sorry, but can you explain what you are trying to say in those last three lines?

Comment: I've edited my question. I would like to know if this is the 302 redirect is a problem?

Comment: No that i snot a problem. Take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 302 HTTP response status code is appropriate for your use (language redirection). Moreover, the 300-class status codes do *not* indicate an error unlike 400-class status codes, which indicate a client error, and the 500-class status codes, which indicate a server error.

A 303 status code may be even better, but for interoperability reasons, 302 is well-understood by all Web browsers. See W3C's ["HTTP/1.1: Status Code Definitions"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for more information.

Comment: ok perfect! Thanks for the reply, I was thinking of doing a 301 redirection to force it but I think it is wrong! So if I go on www.site.com being redirected with a 302 to www.site.com/it/ but in this case Google counts the renk to this page?